# how to add a new table to an existing db in web api c# entity core 2.14

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, mdf

I want to add a new table to an existing mdf db file.
The project is entity core version 2.14. (C# web api)
How can i add the table and update the model folder with the new entity
Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

This question is too general. Please take a look to documentation of EF core about migrations.
https://learn.microsoft.com/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Entity Framework Core is prepared for this kind of change.

Answer (score 0):

To make it faster and easier I highly recommend you to use  "EF Core Power Tools". Add your new table to your db directily using DB management tools. After this use Reverse Engineer option of the EF Core Power Tools to get a new EF code-first code.